# Any word on reified generics in Java?

Tags: java, generics, reification

I know this question will probably provoke more discussion than concrete answers (which I know isn't preferable).  But with the recent acquisition by Oracle, I was wondering if there's been any word that Java might (someday) get reified generics?  I've heard that Oracle wants to give Java a bit of a boost, and I can think of no better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a good article on the discussion of reified generics, [here](http://olabini.com/blog/2010/07/questioning-the-reality-of-generics/), that you should read in regards to Java.  Basically it outlines some of the pitfalls that might happen with the introduction of such a change.  It's fairly brutal for backwards compatibility when you think about it.  Picked it up on [Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com/news) if you're wondering where it came from.

Be grateful that there's talk of [adding closures](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/05/oracle-pushes-a-first-version-of-closures/) to Java.  No more having to slog through with only things like [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/) and their ilk (not that these were bad, on the contrary.)

Comment: Sigh...  It's a good thing Sun/Oracle aren't in charge of building this nation's freeways.  They'd mandate a horse-and-buggy lane at the expense of an express lane.  (Sorry - I know it's not your fault. :-P)

Comment: To steal an idea from douglas adams: adding closures to java is like painting a wheel to make it go faster.

Comment: Adding closures to Java is like adding a steering wheel because people wanted to be able to easily turn their horse-and-buggy.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail I code in Scala. Haven't touched Java in 2 years. Never been happier.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the future beyond Java 7 but it looks like [Reified Generics](http://tech.puredanger.com/java7/#reified) won't be in [Java 7](http://tech.puredanger.com/java7/) (and if Oracle wants to give Java a bit of boost, they should start with releasing Java 7).

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what almost everyone believe, reified Generics is possible in Java, which means that type erasure can be avoided. Actually, it is a trick or pure dark magic if you will.

I've written an article on this at

http://rgomes-info.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/using-typetokens-to-retrieve-generic.html

In the end of the article there's a section on pros and cons of this trick.
Actually, the correct thing would be having "proper" reified Generics in Java and not a trick like this... but unfortunately this is not the case.

Comment: +1 because of the interesting article, but there is a whole class of things you could do with reified generics that you don't get from simply passing the type around. True reified generics are possible with a bit of code generation magic, and, given that asm is like the coolest thing ever, I can't explain why most people don't give it a go.