# A strange error in java generic

Tags: java, generics

This is ok:

```
Class<? extends String> stringClass = "a".getClass();
```

But this gets error:

```
<T> void f(T obj) {
    Class<? extends T> objClass = obj.getClass();
}
```

I know I can cast it like:

```
<T> void f(T obj) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Class<? extends T> objClass = (Class<? extends T>) obj.getClass();
}
```

But why the previous error? Will the next release of Java 7 will support such usage?

**EDIT**

I have no problem dealing with type erasure, and just put the extra `SuppressWarnings` whenever my code is right but the compiler just doesn't support of it.

The question behind is, `SuppressWarnings` is just not enough. When `T.getClass() => ? extends T` is obviously intuitive, why should I have to suppress any warning?

As you have already seen in the javadoc:

> The actual result type is Class where |X| is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called.

The `Object.getClass()` is a special case when we talk about Java generics. It's different to the declared form, which just returns `Classs<?>`. I don't know how IDE like Eclipse stuff  is implemented, in Eclipse IDE, the completion will generate `Class<? extends |X|>` instead of `Class<?>` for you. I guess there maybe some magic stuff in the Object class, to make the base type, which ? extends from, be different between derived types. So, it's just not possible to write your own Object class in Java language, which will return something like `? extends |X|` where `|X|` is `this.getClass()`. But the Java `Object` does, because it's a special case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), this is the signature for `Object.getClass()`:

```
public final Class<?> getClass()
```

It goes on to say

> The actual result type is Class<? extends |X|>
>    where |X| is the erasure
>   of the static type of the expression
>   on which getClass is called.

Class literals are defined in section [15.8.2 in the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.2).

In the first case, the static type of `"a".getClass()` is `String`, so the return type of `getClass()` is `Class<? extends String>`. In the second case, the erasure of `obj` is `Object`, so the return type is `Class<? extends Object>` which is really just `Class<?>`

You might be wondering why `"a".getClass()` does not return `Class<String>`. After all, the compiler "knows" that "a" is a String. The reason is this: when they made `Class` generic, they decided that `Class<T>` should represent a class of type `T`, not a class of some subtype of `T`. The signature of `getClass` falls from that decision and the consequences of inheritance:

```
<T> Class<? extends Number> getType(Number obj) {
   return obj.getClass();
}
```

If you call `getType(Long.valueOf(123)` it will return `Class<? extends Number>`. The expression `"a"` is an object of type `String`. For consistency, `"a".getClass()` must return `Class<? extends String>`

Answer (score 2):

`Class` represents a class in the JVM, not the Java language. So for `List<String>` the actual `Class` is `Class<List>`. In your example, if `T` was `List<String>`, `getClass` will return `Class<? extends List>` as described in the `Object.getClass` API docs.

Comment: That's correct, but I believe the problem the OP is asking about is why the second example does not compile: `found   : java.lang.Class<capture#710 of ? extends java.lang.Object> required: java.lang.Class<? extends T>`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). In the first case, you have an actual concrete type in hand, so `.getClass()` succeeds. In the second case, the actual type of `obj` is erased at runtime, so `.getClass()` can't do better than `Object`.

Reified generics would fix this. According to [Alex Miller's blog](http://tech.puredanger.com/java7/#reified), this feature will not be present in Java 7. That question was also [asked here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359347/any-word-on-reified-generics-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

The declared return type for `getClass` is `Class<?>` so, unfortunately, the compiler only knows that `getClass` will return a capture of `<? extends Object>` which is not the same as capture of `<? extends T>`.

From the javadocs:

```
The actual result type is Class<? extends |X|> where |X| is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called.
```

which is why the version with the explicit cast works.

In your first example the compiler knows the static type of the object is `String` so can do the capture as you would expect.

Note that you *can* do the following:

```
public static <T extends Number> void f(T obj) {
    Class<? extends Number> objClass = obj.getClass();
}
```

because we can guarantee that the static type of `T` is a subclass of `Number`.

Answer (score 0):

`<? extends T>` means a specific subtype of T,

For example, if T is `Exception`, `<? extends T>` can be `RuntimeException` or `SQLException`. You will never know if T.getClass() is  `RuntimeException` or `SQLException`. So explicit cast is needed.